# How to unpack C Style struct of array in Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am using **struct.unpack** to unpack a C styled struct in python. I have a working method but was expecting to optimize and tried the not working method.

C Code:

```
            struct __attribute__((packed))
        {
            struct
            {
                uint16_t A : 4;
                uint16_t B : 12;
            } status;

            int16_t   C;
            int16_t   D;
            int16_t   E;
            int16_t   F[4];
            float32_t G;
        } sampleStruct;
```

Python code:

Working:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F0, F1, F2, F3, G = struct.unpack('<BHhhh4hf', bytes(rx_packet[1:]))
```

Not working:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G = struct.unpack('<BHhhh4hf', bytes(rx_packet[1:]))
```

How can I correct the not working method?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I don't see a way to return part of the format as an array.

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting expected results with those bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is only one array, use an [extended unpacking assignment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```py
#              v pack into F
A, B, C, D, E, *F, G = struct.unpack('<BHhhh4hf', bytes(rx_packet[1:]))
```

The `*F` target will create a list that contains the remainder of items that could not be matched to any previous or later targets.